# Django: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I keep getting this error on my code when the user needs to be redirected to the `ProfileCreateFormView` so they can fill out the form. I tried several browsers and even incognito mode but still the same.

> This page isn’t working
>   127.0.0.1 redirected you too many times.
>   Try clearing your cookies.
>   ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

I'm using Django 2.1 and python 3.7

```
class LoginFormView(auth_views.LoginView):

    template_name = 'users/login.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        url = reverse_lazy(
            'users:profile', kwargs={'pk': self.request.user.id})
        return url

class ProfileDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):

    template_name = 'users/profile.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = models.Profile.objects.all()
        return qs

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.object = self.request.user.profiles
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return redirect(reverse_lazy('users:create_profile'))
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)


class ProfileCreateFormView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):

    template_name = 'users/create_profile.html'
    form_class = forms.ProfileForm
```

---

**urls.py**

```
app_name = 'users'

urlpatterns = [
    path('profile/<pk>/', views.ProfileDetailView.as_view(), name='profile'),
    path('profile/create-profile/', views.ProfileCreateFormView.as_view(), name='create_profile'),
]
```

Comment: Where is the URL for that detail view?

Comment: It typically caused by an infinite redirect loop. Check your log (from web server / runserver / etc), for clues. Maybe the login view redirects to create-profile, which redirects back to login (due to LoginRequiredMixin). Just a guess. But it seems that there's at least one route / view involved in the redirect loop that's not included in the question.

Comment: what's your login view ? `settings.LOGIN_URL`

Comment: @HåkenLid I tried removing the `LoginRequiredMixin` from the class but the issue still persists. the only info showing in my runserver is `[04/Nov/2018 16:55:51] "GET /users/profile/create-profile/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0` which I can't find helpful.

Comment: @HåkenLid this is the value in my settings `LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('users:login')`

Comment: My guess is that your `self.request.user.profiles` raises an `ObjectDoesNotExist` which causes a redirect loop.

Comment: @HåkenLid you're right, I just checked it loops multiple times however I can't find a way to filter it. I tried something like `if self.request.user.profiles.exists()` but it doesn't work.